# install SWIG python package in windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, binding, swig

i created a test c dll, which export one function i would like to expose to python bindings. I used the latest version fo SWIG for that. After successful compilation, SWIG leaves me with a x.py and a x.dll file.

Now i am supposed to "import" the "package". However, no matter where i copy those files, when i type "import x" in python i get "ImportError: No module named 'x'".

So how do i load such a custom created package in python?

I am running windows 7 x64, with python 3.3 and latest SWIG.

thanks

edit: we are getting somewhere! I did some path trickery, now the module is found, but:

```
      File "C:\Python33\lib\imp.py", line 119, in load_source
        _LoadSourceCompatibility(name, pathname, file).load_module(name)
      File ".\_pt1.py", line 28, in <module>
        _pt1 = swig_import_helper()
      File ".\_pt1.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
        _mod = imp.load_module('_pt1', fp, pathname, description)
      File "C:\Python33\lib\imp.py", line 180, in load_module
        return load_source(name, filename, file)
      File "C:\Python33\lib\imp.py", line 119, in load_source
        _LoadSourceCompatibility(name, pathname, file).load_module(name)
      File ".\_pt1.py", line 28, in <module>
        _pt1 = swig_import_helper()
      File ".\_pt1.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
        _mod = imp.load_module('_pt1', fp, pathname, description)
      File "C:\Python33\lib\imp.py", line 180, in load_module
        return load_source(name, filename, file)
      File "C:\Python33\lib\imp.py", line 119, in load_source
        _LoadSourceCompatibility(name, pathname, file).load_module(name)
      File ".\_pt1.py", line 28, in <module>
        _pt1 = swig_import_helper()
      File ".\_pt1.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
        _mod = imp.load_module('_pt1', fp, pathname, description)
      File "C:\Python33\lib\imp.py", line 180, in load_module
        return load_source(name, filename, file)
      File "C:\Python33\lib\imp.py", line 119, in load_source
        _LoadSourceCompatibility(name, pathname, file).load_module(name)
      File ".\_pt1.py", line 28, in <module>
        _pt1 = swig_import_helper()
      File ".\_pt1.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
        _mod = imp.load_module('_pt1', fp, pathname, description)
      File "C:\Python33\lib\imp.py", line 180, in load_module
        return load_source(name, filename, file)
      File "C:\Python33\lib\imp.py", line 119, in load_source
        _LoadSourceCompatibility(name, pathname, file).load_module(name)
      File ".\_pt1.py", line 28, in <module>
        _pt1 = swig_import_helper()
      File ".\_pt1.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
        _mod = imp.load_module('_pt1', fp, pathname, description)
      File "C:\Python33\lib\imp.py", line 180, in load_module
        return load_source(name, filename, file)
      File "C:\Python33\lib\imp.py", line 119, in load_source
        _LoadSourceCompatibility(name, pathname, file).load_module(name)
      File ".\_pt1.py", line 28, in <module>
        _pt1 = swig_import_helper()
      File ".\_pt1.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
        _mod = imp.load_module('_pt1', fp, pathname, description)
      File "C:\Python33\lib\imp.py", line 180, in load_module
        return load_source(name, filename, file)
      File "C:\Python33\lib\imp.py", line 119, in load_source
        _LoadSourceCompatibility(name, pathname, file).load_module(name)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 584, in _check_name_wrapper
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1022, in load_module
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1003, in load_module
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 560, in module_for_loader_wrapper
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 853, in _load_module
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 954, in get_code
      File "C:\Python33\lib\imp.py", line 106, in get_data
        return super().get_data(path)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1032, in get_data
    RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

where pt1 is my test module.

edit2:

I have uploaded all the files here: (40kb) rghost.net/53170317

Comment: See [using distutils](http://swig.org/Doc3.0/Python.html#Python_nn6) (SWIG 3.0 docs). Also read [Distributing Python Modules](http://docs.python.org/3/distutils) and the [Python Packaging User Gudie](http://packaging.python.org).

Comment: Please indicate where you have put the files and tried, and how you ran python

Comment: thanks, that helped. I added the leading underscore "_" to the files. Now they are found, but it fails with a recursion bug. I pasted the log into the first post.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have foo.py and x.py and _x.dll, try putting them all in the same folder. Then, python.exe foo.py (where foo.py is module that imports x) from that folder. Post what happens in your question.

Update: just noticed the `.\_pt1.py` import. Can you find where that module is and see if it contains an `import x` or other suspicious looking code that could cause recursion.

Comment: thanks for your reply, i am getting increasingly desperate. :(

When i do what you describe, i get the exact same import-recursion error i already appended to my question.


I have uploaded all the files here: (40kb)


http://rghost.net/53170317